# Any ideas to displaying a component just on the left side if there are odd number of components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a 2 column grid component like the image below. If there is an odd number of components say 5,  there should be two rows of 2 and one row of single component placed to the left.
But the problem I am having is that, my 5th component is going to the full width and it is not to the left. It should like [this pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/assLP.jpg). How can I make the 5th component to just stay on the left and not the full width, when there are odd number of components?

If I remove the `flex: 1 1 auto;` from my CSS it works, BUT the issue is, when I shrink the window size, then the components that don't have description(example second component)  is not going to the full width. Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd2bV.jpg

**Note:** I can't modify the HTML. I can only change the CSS.

Here is my CSS and HTML:

CSS:

```
.myWrapper
 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 102.5%;
    float: left;
    margin: -10px;
 }
.myContentBox 
{
   flex: 1 1 auto;
}

<div class="myWrapper">
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6"></div>  
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6"></div>
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6"></div>
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6"></div>
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

[image].

Answer (score 0):

Try using grid instead of flex.

Check out this working example.
https://jsfiddle.net/mnfghd7t/7/

HTML

```
  <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Refer this to learn more about grid.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-css-grid-in-5-minutes-f582e87b1228/

Comment: I can't change the HTML.  Only the CSS I can change.

Comment: no need to change the html.
Treat your myWrapper as grid-container in my code and myContentBox as grid-item

Comment: Using grid did not work. where is the col-sm-6 col-md-6 in your html?

Comment: can you please share your code ? working playground like fiddle ?

Comment: I shared it on the top of my question. But my question is how come you don't have the col-sm-6 col-md-6 in your html?

Comment: I don't have the col-sm-6 col-md-6 in my html because i didn't use bootstrap. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226277/discussion-between-myles-enist-and-keshav).

Comment: I guess my question is how do we do this with my bootstrap in my html? Like I said,  I can't change my html.

Answer (score 0):

Is this satisfy you requirement?

```css
.myWrapper
 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
 }
.myContentBox 
{
   width: 49%;
   background: red;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="myWrapper">
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6">1</div>  
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6">2</div>
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6">3</div>
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6">4</div>
<div class="myContentBox col-sm-6 col-md-6">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with removing the `flex: 1 1 auto;` is that, the  components that don't have a description will not go to the full width when you shrink the Window size. example here: https://imgur.com/a/VAMGYK4 . As you can see, the top component is not going to the full window size as the bottom component.